# Parse Error T_String Line 188 Why? (Expecting comma or semicolon)

Tags: php, parsing

```
  187  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  188   echo "<tr><td><a href="edit_customer.php?nid=<?
        echo($row['sold_to_party_code']); ?>&page=<? echo(curPageURL()); ?
         >">      
        <img src="images/ico_edit_16.png" 
        class="icon16 fl-space2" alt="" title="edit" />
```

Why am I getting a parse error for line 188?   it says it got a string but expected a , or ;

Comment: You've got an unescaped `"`, you've got a `<?php` tag within something that's already PHP, and more.

Comment: i'm a noob obviously.  it worked before back in 2011.  maybe a difference php version allowed that syntax?

Comment: I've been using PHP since 1999. It has never allowed the syntax you're posting.